# Clog with Siphon jet vs gravity feed toilet

Tags: toilet, drain, clog

I want to replace my old toilet and I was doing some research between gravity fed vs siphonic jet toilets.

When it comes to clogging, according to Internet, gravity fed toilets are better because it has straight trap way compare to S shaped trapway in siphonic jet toilets.

But wouldn't straight trapway in gravity fed toilets increase the chances of small objects (e.g toys) ending up in the toilet drain line rather than getting stuck somewhere in S trap of siphonic jet toilets? I guess unclogging the drain line would be more costly compare to unclogging the S trap.

There are 2 types of clogs -

1. toilet papers that won't disintegrate well, paper towels, and all other things which can be cleared using plunger, draino and augers.
2. hard objects which draino or plunger can't remove, because it is stuck somewhere in the line.

For 1st type of clogs, I agree that gravity fed toilets are better, but my question is for 2nd type of clogs.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The objects only get stuck if you flush the toilet, so do not flush until sure what is in it

Comment: @Ruskes  Never had kids?

Comment: The trap in a toilet is typically a smaller diameter and tighter bend radius than the drain pipe it empties into. Any toy or other similar hard object which makes it through the trap should move freely down the drain pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You are going at this the wrong way.

Know that toilet only clogs **AFTER** flushing attempt and not before.

This requires adult looking what is in the toilet before flushing.

Left unattended kids will flush what ever is in it, since it is fascinating to see stuff disappear.

The simple DIY solution is to use a blocking device on toilet flush.

[image: flush stop]

Comment: This is assuming that children are the offenders, and also assuming the flush mechanism is activated by a handle.

Comment: Sad state of the world when we have to lock our flush handles also.